# building cryptopp 5.6.2 with msvc 2010

Tags: c++, encryption, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build cryptopp 5.6.2 with msvc 2010. According to `Readme.txt` file in project's directory, if you want to compile project as a static library that contains all algorithms, you should build `cryptest` project. So i select this project from solutions and try to build it. But i get this message :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cryptest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 12/30/2013 9:43:43 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Win32\cryptest\Debug\cryptest.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  adhoc.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'adhoc.cpp': No such file or directory
1>  bench.cpp
1>  bench2.cpp
1>  datatest.cpp
1>  dlltest.cpp
1>  fipsalgt.cpp
1>  regtest.cpp
1>  test.cpp
1>  validat1.cpp
1>  validat2.cpp
1>  validat3.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:26.23
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There is adhoc.cpp.PROTO in project's firectory. I change it's suffix to .cpp and try to build it again. But i get this Message :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cryptest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 12/30/2013 9:51:24 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Win32\cryptest\Debug\cryptest.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  adhoc.cpp
1>  bench.cpp
1>  bench2.cpp
1>  datatest.cpp
1>  dlltest.cpp
1>  fipsalgt.cpp
1>  regtest.cpp
1>  test.cpp
1>  validat1.cpp
1>  validat2.cpp
1>  validat3.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'E:\Utality for Windows\crypto\cryptopp\Win32\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:27.22
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

So does that library exist?

`E:\Utality for Windows\crypto\cryptopp\Win32\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib`

If not, then you need to build that library from the cryptopp sources (and I am sure it is more files than what your build log is showing).

Comment: 'So does that library exist? If not, then you need to build that ... '. I just try to build the library according to building rules published by library's author nothing else. "E:\Utality for Windows\crypto\cryptopp\Win32\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib" is the path of compiled library, not a pre-built binary needed for compiling process.